# Syntx Error with IF ELSE in batch-file

Tags: batch-file

I am interested in messing with batch files and I am making a batch file to copy the contents of a drive. When I run it, the program stops when the IF statement happens. How can I fix this?

```
    @echo on
    TITLE Full Drive Back-up
    ECHO 1- "E:"
    ECHO 2- "F:"
    ECHO 3- "G:"
    SET /P choice=Which Drive would you like to backup: || Set choice=404
    ECHO:

    IF "%choice%" == "1" (
    ECHO Copying "E:"
    COPY "E:\" "D:\Desktop - data drive\Coding\Windows\Backup Storage\E"
    )

    IF %choice%==2 (
    ECHO Copying "F:"
    COPY "F:\" "D:\Desktop - data drive\Coding\Windows\Backup Storage\F"
    )

    IF %choice%==3 (
    ECHO Copying "G:"
    COPY "G:\" "D:\Desktop - data drive\Coding\Windows\Backup Storage\G"
    )
    PAUSE
```

Thank you for reading this far, have a good day.

Comment: `(` has to be on the same line as `if`.

Comment: ...as you did in the first `if`

Comment: @SomethingDark Thank you very much.

Comment: @Compo Thank you as well